# Connection using uniobject.NET connection to unidata account does not work and transaction fails

Tags: unidata, u2, uniobjects, u2netdk, rocket-u2

I am using Uniobject.Net for connection to unidata account. Connection is successful but while using the transaction processing it fails during transaction commit. It says "No Transaction is in progress" in the client side message. We used user with root permission as well but still the get the same issue. If we use telnet connection it works well.

Can anyone help me with this issue? Is there a log created for uniobject.Net call in unidata?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling a Unidata Basic program on the UD server that includes the instructions begin/commit/end transaction or are you using the uniObjects session transaction class?

If it's in the called basic program, then TP should work the same in .net call or telnet. If calling using the uo.net transaction class, it may well not match the telnet result as the transaction is happening at the .net session level (which can't happen in the telnet session). Check the isActive() class method to see if you do really have an active transaction.

Logging for uniObjects.net is set up in the app.config or web.config file. See the "Administrative Server Settings and Logging for U2 Clients" document for details on how to.

Comment: Actually, we are using a third party software to connect to unidata that uses the uniobject.NET connection. That software has many basic subroutines which uses TRANSACTION BEGIN/COMMIT.

Comment: I am looking for the log that is generated in UNIDATA side not in the client side as we are using third party software to cannot configure that. 

Just for information: I am using UNIDATA on Linux system.

Comment: If you add this file in $UDTHOME

cat $UDTHOME/serverdebug
udcs 9 /tmp/udcs.log

You will see some detailed logs for uniobjects, after restarting unidata, sadly.

Comment: Ian McGowan, I have that file in my $UDTHOME directory but the file name is "SERVERDEBUG" instead of "serverdebug". Does that make any difference? Also, this file does not specify the file name "/tmp/udcs.log". I think, if we do not specify the file name it should write the file with name "udapiserver_<pid>.log under "/tmp". Please correct me if i am missing anything.